# How to make graphs with charts.js and symfony 3

Tags: javascript, symfony, chart.js, pie-chart

here I would like to have graphs in my admin dashboard with charts.js.The graphs should include the number of registered doctors, the number of appointments and finally the number of appointments honored.And for that I I opted for the chart type Pie Chart, which will group all three.
**Here is my controller where I get the numbers of registered doctors, appointments and honored appointments**:

```
   public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

    // on recuppere le user connecte ensuite on met dans la session toutes les infos conncernant le medecin
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if ($user === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Utilisateur Inexistant');
    } else {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $medecin = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin')->findAll();
        $booking = $em->getRepository('DoctixFrontBundle:Booking')->findAll();

        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->set('medecin', $medecin);
        $session->set('booking', $booking);


        $nbdoc = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(m.id) AS nbr_doc FROM DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin m ')
            ->getResult();

         $nbbookings =  $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(b.id) AS nbr_booking FROM DoctixFrontBundle:Booking b ')
            ->getResult();

          $nbbookhonored = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(b.id) AS nbr_booking_honored FROM DoctixFrontBundle:Booking b WHERE b.statut like :approved ')
            ->setParameter('approved','approved') 
            ->getResult(); 


    return $this->render('DoctixAdminBundle:Admin:index.html.twig', array(
                'nbdoc' => $nbdoc,
                'nbbookings' => $nbbookings,
                'nbbookhonored' => $nbbookhonored
             ));
   }
}
```

**Twig file**

```
<h2></h2>
<div class="box_general padding_bottom">
    <div class="header_box version_2">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Statistiques</h2>
    </div>
    <canvas id="myAreaChart" width="100%" height="30" style="margin:45px 0 15px 0;"></canvas> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <!-- Example Pie Chart Card-->
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i> Pie Chart Example</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                 <canvas id="myPieChart" width="100%" height="100"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="datas" data-items="{{ nbdoc|json_encode }}"></div>
<div id="datas" data-items="{{ nbbookings|json_encode }}"></div>
<div id="datas" data-items="{{ nbbookhonored|json_encode }}"></div>
```

**Charts.js**

```js
// Chart.js scripts
// -- Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';
Chart.defaults.global.title.display = true;
Chart.defaults.global.title.text = "Evolution de mes Rendez-vous";
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 5 ;
// -- Area Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById('myAreaChart').getContext('2d');

let root = document.querySelector("#datas");
let jsondata = root.dataset.items
jsondata = JSON.parse(jsondata)
 
tabMedecins =[]
tabMois =[]
jsondata.forEach( val =>{
    tabMedecins.push(val.nbr_rdv)
    tabMois.push(val.mois)
})

console.log("Nb de RDVs="+ tabMedecins);
console.log("Mois="+ tabMois);

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: tabMedecins, 
        datasets: [{
            label: "Le nombre de RDVs/mois",
            lineTension: 0.3,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointHitRadius: 20,
            pointBorderWidth: 2,
            data: tabMois,
        }],
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                time: {
                    unit: 'date'
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                },
                ticks: {
                    maxTicksLimit: 5
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 12,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5
                },
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)",
                }
            }],
        },
        legend: {
            display: true
        }
    }
});

// pie chart

var canvas = document.getElementById("myPieChart").getContext('2d');

//let root1 = document.querySelector('#datas');
//let  jsondata = root1.dataset.items
jsondata = JSON.parse(jsondata)
//nombre de RDVs par mois
console.log("Mes Stats:"+jsondata);
 
nbrdoc =[]
nbrbooking =[]
nbbookhonored = []
jsondata.forEach( val =>{
    nbrdoc.push(val.nbr_doc)
    nbrbooking.push(val.nbr_booking)
    nbbookhonored.push(val. nbr_booking_honored)
})

console.log("Nb de docs="+ nbrdoc);
console.log("Nb de bookings="+ nbrbooking);

var myPieChart = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Nombre de médecins inscrits", "Nombre de rendez-vous", "Nombre de rendez-vous honorés"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [nbrdoc, nbrbooking, nbbookhonored],
            backgroundColor: ['#007bff', '#dc3545', '#ffc107'],
        }],
    },
});
```

In my charts.js file, the Area example works fine, but if I add the Pie Charts as a result of the code I have no display. I would like to see my pie charts with the number of registered doctors, the number of appointments, and the number of honored appointments, but I have nothing displayed.Thanks

**The result of my var_dump on  number of registered doctors, the number of appointments, and the number of honored appointments**

```
  array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["nbr_doc"]=> string(1) "4" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["nbr_booking"]=> string(2) "27" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["nbr_booking_honored"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

Comment: Can you also write result of your `nbrdoc, nbrbooking, nbbookhonored`, variables?

Comment: Hi @Alien, i've updated my post in adding the result of nbrdoc, nbrbooking, nbbookhonored.

Comment: Hi, as I can see, you have hash arrays what you are trying to add to chart data, as chart is not so smart, you need to send only data in format like `[4, 27, 1]`. I'm not sure If you are going to have more same elements in one array? If this will be like now, you should get data like `nbrdoc[0]["nbr_doc"]` then you will get nubmer, do same for all 3. If you will have more in one, then you need to map numbers and sum them. Try to play a little bit :)

Comment: Hi @Alien, I tried your comment, but I still have no display of my graph

Comment: Hi, you have some errors in code, when snippet is runned it gives error `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'jsondata' has already been declared"` two times declaring same var `jsondata`

Comment: Hi, @Alien, i've updated my charts.js code, the problem is that in my code charts.js, I made an example with the Chart Area that worked, but that was in another view (twig file) .And as a result of the Chart Area, I added that of the Pie Chart, but it does not work. I'm completely lost

Comment: Have you included your `Chart.js` to twig file?I can't see it in twig file. you should go step by step, like first include file. then try only to get data and print it with `console.log` and so on... One more thing you should use unique ids in html, you have 3 same ids for different data, they can overwrite each other.

Comment: yes it's included in my main base.html.twig.and if I understand correctly I have to put the three data in the same id ?

Comment: As you wish, all in one, or change ids to have 3 different ids.